# XAMPP's PHPMyAdmin Ignores AUTO_INCREMENT Attribute When Exporting the Table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

The problem that I am going to tell is for all the tables in the DB, When I dump my DB it ignores `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute. My actual table is as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `departments` (
  `departmentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chairid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default_department.png',
  `url` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But if I dump the table using PHPMyAdmin it does not add `auto_increment` which I mentioned before.

The output of the exported .sql file's content is here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `departments` (
  `departmentid` int(11) NOT NULL, -- AUTO_INCREMENT is missing
  `chairid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default_department.png',
  `url` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I especially checked that if `auto_increment` is disabled in `CREATE TABLE` options but no, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in phpMyAdmin version 4.5.0.1 (Sep 2015):

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11492

Answer (score 0):

I supposed it ignores auto increment but I explore file and at the bottom of sql I found that it altered to auto increment somewhere else